# Passing object from Java to Fitness

Tags: java, fitnesse

I am writing an automated test in Fitness and need to pass an object from Java to Fitness and then validate it. Does anyone know how to accomplish that?

Comment: @Javant Hover over the tag, and click info to go to the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/fitnesse/info).

Answer (score 1):

That should be all described in the [Two Minute Example](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.TwoMinuteExample). Take a look at the Fixture Code section.